# Is the function $e^{-|x|^k}$ analytic on any interval not containing zero?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let $k \in(0,\infty)$ , is the function $e^{-|x|^k}$ real analytic for any $(a,b)$ such that $a>0$.

To show analyticity on an interval  $(a,b)$ we need to show that there exists a $C>0$ such that 
\begin{align}
\left| \frac{d^m}{dx^m}  e^{-|x|^k} \right| \le C^{m+1} m!, \forall x\in (a,b)
\end{align}

I think, for $|x|>a>0$ can also show the bound of the form

\begin{align}
\left| \frac{d^m}{dx^m}  e^{-|x|^k} \right| \le  C^{m+1} |x|^{2(k-1)}e^{-|x|^k}
\end{align}

which would imply the analyticity?  But I am not sure how to do that.

**Edit:** By composition theorem, we have that $e^{-|x|^k}$ is analytic on any interval away from zero.  See answers below.

However, I would like to get a proof by showing that a bound of the type holds  $\left| \frac{d^m}{dx^m}  e^{-|x|^k} \right| \le  C^{m+1} |x|^{2(k-1)}e^{-|x|^k}$.

Comment: Can't you use that composition of analytic functions is analytic?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, that I already got. I am not looking at a more direct proof. I really want see if bound is correct $\left| \frac{d^m}{dx^m}  e^{-|x|^k} \right| \le  C^{m+1} |x|^{2(k-1)}e^{-|x|^k}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: If $a < x < b$, then $|x| = x$, and $|x|^{k} = x^{k}$ is real-analytic ([Newton's binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem)), and a composition of real-analytic functions is real-analytic.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I thought. Is my bound on the derivatives correct $e^{-|x|^k} \right| \le  C^{m+1} |x|^{2(k-1)}e^{-|x|^k}?

Comment: Your bound looks close, but not quite OK. One definitive test on a prospective bound is induction on $m$.

Comment: Not really sure how to do it via induction. Can you show or sketch a proof?

Answer (score 1):

The requested bound cannot hold.

From

$$\left(e^P\right)'=P'e^P,\\\left(Qe^P\right)'=(Q'+QP')e^P=Re^P$$

we deduce that the degree of the polynomial factor in front of the exponential follows the recurrence

$$\begin{cases}q=0\to r=p-1,\\q>0\to r=pq-1.\end{cases}$$

Then with $P=-x^k$, the degrees are $0,k-1,k^2-k-1,k^3-k^2-k-1,\cdots k^m-\frac{k^m-1}{k-1}$, and grow much larger than $2(k-1)$.

Comment: Thanks. So, what is the bound?  Is it  $C^{m+1} |x|^{2k^m} e^{-|x|^k}$?

Comment: @Lisa: where do you see $2k^m$ ?

Comment: I thought you said that it grows like $2k^m$?

Comment: @Lisa: where do you see such an expression ?

Comment: I was looking into generalizations of Laplace distributions and wanted to show these type of bounds for the derivatives.  But I can't determine the dominating terms. Would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: @Lisa: I just did, didn't I ?

Comment: Sorry, for being slow.  What is the exponent in polynomial term, then?

Comment: @lisa: it is written in the answer.

Comment: So, the bond is  $C^{k+1}  |x|^{k^m -\frac{k^m-1}{k-1}} e^{-|x|^k}$, is this correct?

Comment: @lisa: yep but I have not investigated the constant coefficients.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  But all we have to claim is that such a constant exists. Which I think it does, right? Since, we are looking at fixed intervals $(a,b)$

Comment: @Lisa: you can't decide if it exists without checking the growth speed of the constant coefficients with $m$. It may not be superexponential.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.  Is that something difficult to do? How would one go about doing that?