# Show $\left| \frac{d^m}{dx^m} e^{-|x|^k} \right| \le C^{m+1} |x|^{2(k-1)}e^{-|x|^k}, \forall |x|>a$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, analyticity

How to show the following bound:

Let $k \in (0,\infty)$ and let $  |x|>a>0$, then there exists $C>0$ sucht that for all $m\ge 1$

\begin{align}
\left| \frac{d^m}{dx^m}  e^{-|x|^k} \right| \le  C^{m+1} |x|^{2(k-1)}e^{-|x|^k}, \forall |x|>a
\end{align}

This question was raised [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371573/is-the-function-e-xk-analytic-on-any-interval-not-containing-zero/2371588#2371588) where it was also pointed out that the bound is almost there but not correct.  The proof by induction was also suggested, but I am not sure how to do that.